# how to get the return value from a JS dialog box in asp.net without tying it to a button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can one display a confirmation box & get the return value in C# code in ASP.NET without tying it to a button? I need to display the confirmation box from inside the event handler of a button if a certain condition is filled.

Situation:

```
protected void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (blah)
    {
        bool answer = DisplayConfirmationBox();
    }
}
```

Displaying it using JS is not really an issue, but getting the return value from it is.

Comment: You can store return value in a hidden field and trigger a postback.

Comment: You're going to need to initiate a post-back to the server with the result of the `window.confirm`, otherwise the server can't know about it. If you simply need to know on the server, you could look at sending the data back via AJAX

Comment: does this help? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/359929/Display-Confirmation-BOX-yes-no-on-ASP-NET-Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is executed on the client, ASP.NET/C# on the server.

To get the value from your JS Dialog Box to the server, so you can work with it in your server side code, you have to either store it in a (Hidden) Text Field and perform a PostBack or do an asynchronous AJAX request.

For the first method see the [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) server control and to trigger a PostBack from JS you can use

```
__doPostBack(control, arg);
```

Comment: wtf I just tried this approach and it worked the first time although I don't know shit about javascript or ASP.NET. this is crazy!